# Factorygirl nested class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hi I have a class named `class Admin::Admin < ActiveRecord::Base`
And I have a factory called

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_admin do
```

However, I keep on getting `uninitialized constant AdminAdmin` when I run the spec test that uses this factory.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, you should define your factorygirl as the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_admin, class: Admin::Admin do |f|
```